# 8h layover in Sydney on my way back to Singapore, can I roam Sydney without a visa?

Tags: australia, layovers, sydney

Going to Fiji soon and my flight back to Singapore from Fiji is a dreadful 8-hour layover in Sydney.

I have friends in Sydney and wondering if I can take an exit from the airport and come back WITHOUT a visa. My nationality requires me to have a visa to visit Australia but quite unsure if I will be allowed this time since I am on transit.

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: Note: transit generally means you're staying in the airport...visas are to let  you leave the airport...

Answer (score 7):

If your nationality requires a visa to visit Australia, then you will need a visa to visit friends in Sydney.

Answer (score 3):

[This page](http://www.immi.gov.au/Visit/Pages/Visit.aspx) will assist you to determine if you need a visa, and what type. If you wish to leave the transit lounge for a few hours only then you will most probably require a [transit visa (subclass 771)](http://www.immi.gov.au/Visas/Pages/771.aspx).